# CPU-cache: distinguish whether a data in cache is an address (pointer) or a value?

Tags: caching, memory, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu

Is there a way to know whether a data stored in cache is an address (i.e. pointer) or an actual value?

It seems one possible way is to drop a hint by software and compiler. But I don't know details how to achieve this or how feasible it is. Can anyone give me some advice or point me with some references?

Otherwise, is it possible to distinguish an address/value by their binary bit patterns? Is this a trustable approach?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: bits that software consider addresses and bits that software considers data cannot be distinguished by the hardware.  Think about pointer manipulation *p++, for example, how is that done?  The address bits are fed to the alu as if they are data, which they are, then the result is just bits that might be considered an address.  If you want to tell a pointer from data in ram, it is all language and all compiler.

Comment: The comment of dwelch is completely right for most computers. There were, however, a few architectures with "tagged memory" that distinguish between addresses and data on the hardware level, see <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture>.

Answer (score 1):

A CPU's cache only caches data. A pointer is data (and that data happens to be interpreted as an address by code). Any assembly language programmer will probably tell you that (at least for most CPUs) the CPU is happy to treat integer or floating point data as an address too (types and type checking are mostly just an illusion created by compilers).

Now consider a cache line that contains 2 floating point values and 2 pointers' data. It would be infeasible for a CPU to only cache the parts of the cache line that contains floating point data while not caching the parts of the cache line that contain pointer data; even if the CPU knew what types of data were where within the cache line.

Comment: Thanks Brendan! Suppose I can somehow modify the compiler and the ISA, such that the compiler can detect the pointer type data and will set a flag (indicating it's a pointer, which requires ISA support)? And the flag will be stored by an extra bit associated with the data in memory/cache. How difficulty do you think this will be? Any other comments on this?